# How to get GWT textbox value from selenium webdriver?

Tags: html, gwt, selenium

I'm trying to test my GWT application using selenium, the html generated by GWT Textbox is shown as below:

```
<input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox" >
```

No value there, but from UI i can see the text, Is there a way to get the value from selenium?

UPDATE: I can locate the `input` from selenium, but can not get its value, for example the value of above `input` is "blahblah...",  which i can see from page UI, but can't get from the above html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each widget should have a id for selenium testing. Here selenium does not identify element, and you are not able to get value which are on UI. so you have to set id for input widget.
i.e

```
TextBox textField= new TextBox();    
textField.getElement().setId("name");
```

Comment: To set IDs only for testing (and not have them in production), use `ensureDebugId` instead, see the end of https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/testing_methodologies_using_gwt and http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#ensureDebugId(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, however maybe i didn't make it clear: i CAN get the `input` element from selenium driver, but i can't get the value, even from web page i can see the value there. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mike it may be WebElement issue. use getAttribute instead of getText.

Comment: Sorry maybe not, the problem here is i can't get the actual value, see my update above.

Comment: @Mike did you set any `id` of that element? because your updated code still don't have any id. it's mandatory to have id of element. you have to set explicitly.

Comment: @Bhumika It works, using getAttribute("value") works, i was just thinking there is no `value` attribute out there and it might not work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Bhumika is correct, having a unique `id` attribute for every element you would want to manipulate is good programming practice.  But if you don't have that and can't get it added, you still have a good handle on this particular case: the `placeholder` attribute.  To locate the element, use the XPath `//input[@placeholder='Input note title...']`.  To obtain the value of the field, get its `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Like @BMT said, you should get the value using getAttribute, like this

GWT Code

```
TextBox textField = new TextBox(); 
textField.ensureDebugId("textFieldId");
```

Selenium Code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("textFieldId")).getAttribute("value");
```

You could see all the properties (visible or invisible) of one element using Inspect Element Tool of browsers (F12), then get the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the resulting DOM to look like

```
<input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox" value="myValue">
```

you'll have to use

```
textBox.getElement().setAttribute("value", "myValue");
```

instead of

```
textBox.setText("myValue")
```

That's because `setText` will only update the `value` *property* (i.e. `theDomElement.value = "myValue"`), which will **not** update the `value` *attribute* (i.e. `<input value="myValue"/>`).

When updating a property, the browser will not update the associated attribute.